# doxygen and sorting overloaded C++ functions

Tags: doxygen

With `SORT_MEMBER_DOCS=YES` the order of overloaded functions seems to be undefined.

Is it possible to have all the members sorted, with exception of functions that have the same name?

I'd like to keep overloads in the same order as in the source, because usually the first overload has more extensive documentation and the next one refers to it.

**UPDATE:**
some time after asking this question I looked into the source and proposed a patch for Doxygen
https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=646533 and
this issue was fixed in ver. 1.7.4. The order of overloaded functions is preserved now.